# Android Native JNI Parcel read Data

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native, parcel

I have the following CPP code that can be compiled using NDK:

```
char *byteData = hexToByte("41540D0A");
Parcel req,;
req.writeInterfaceToken(String16("com.android.systemui"));
req.writeInt32(sizeof(byteData));
printf("original size is = %d\n", sizeof(byteData));
printf("read size is = %d\n", req.readInt32());
req.write(byteData, sizeof(byteData));
req.writeInt32(255);
```

When I compile and run the code I got:

```
original size is = 4
read size is = 0
```

What is the error with me or what is the right way to read all data from Parcel in Android ?

Comment: Well, where does this `Parcel` class come from and how is it implemented?

Comment: #include <binder/Parcel.h>

Comment: I thought you were supposed to use [AParcel](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/ndk-binder#aparcel) when using the NDK. In any case, all those `write` functions return a status code, so you should check which status codes you get.

Comment: All write commands return zero results

Comment: Ok, well as far as I can tell, reads and writes both increase the Parcel's internal data position. So to read back that Int32 you'll have to call `setDataPosition` with the correct position (easiest might be something like `setDataPosition(dataPosition() - sizeof(int32_t))`).

Comment: Using `setDataPosition` I got results when use `read(void *, len)` But how i will got the len to read if i want to read reply from `binder->transcat` ? I tried `dataSize()` but it is not correct